# Ruby program help (ATM program)

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm a newb Ruby user using Ruby version 2.1.5p273 and below I created an Atm simulator program that takes user input of deposits and withdrawals, and then it displays the balance after.  I am struggling with ifs, elses and loops.  I want to put a decision making statement in the beginning, that asks if the user wants to withdraw, deposit, check balance, or end your session.  I also want to put a decision making  statement in the end, that asks if the user wants to continue (which would go back to the beginning, or end the session).  My general idea of what I want it to look like would be below, the overall program is below the idea code.  I know it's wrong but it's just what I want it to look like, so any help in making it into correct and working code would be greatly appreciated.

```
print "Would you like to (w)ithdraw, (d)eposit, or (c)heck your balance or (e)nd your session?
if "(w)ithdraw"  # i'd like to make this do a "press w for withdraw"           
   bank_account.withdraw
elsif "(d)eposit"   #  i'd like to make this do a "press d for deposit"
   bank_account.deposit
elsif "(c)heck your balance" #  i'd like to make this do a "press c to check your balance" 
bank_account.show_balance
elseif "(e)nd your session" #  i'd like to make this do a "press e to end your session"
end




#This program is an ATM simulator, it takes user input of deposits and withdrawals, and then     displays the balance after.

class BankAccount

  def initialize(name)
   @transations = []
   @balance = 0
  end

  def deposit
   print "How much would you like to deposit? "
   amount = gets.chomp
   @balance += amount.to_f
   puts "$#{amount} deposited."
  end

  def withdraw
   print "How much would you like to withdraw?"
   amount = gets.chomp
   @balance -= amount.to_f
   puts "#{amount} withdrawn"
  end

  def show_balance
   puts "Your balance is #{@balance}"
  end


end

bank_account = BankAccount.new("Justin G")
bank_account.class # => BankAccount

print "Welcome to Jay's ATM!\n"
bank_account.deposit
bank_account.show_balance
bank_account.withdraw
`enter code here`bank_account.show_balance
puts "Thank you"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly rudimentary but should get you started. Please let me know if you have additional questions on what I'm doing in the code. For the most part it should be fairly self-explanatory if you're familiar with other object-oriented programming languages.

Here's your ATM:

```
# atm.rb

require './bank_account.rb'

cmd = ""
account = BankAccount.new("Justin G")

puts "***Welcome to #{account.name}'s ATM***\n\n"

while cmd != "e" do
  puts "Would you like to (w)ithdraw, (d)eposit or (c)heck your balance?"
  puts "You can also (e)nd your session."
  cmd = gets.chomp

  case cmd
  when "w"
    puts "How much would you like to withdraw?"
    amount = gets.chomp # expect this to be a float

    # handle incorrect input somehow, either here or
    # preferably in the BankAccount#withdraw method
    account.withdraw(amount)
  when "d"
    puts "How much would you like to deposit?"
    amount = gets.chomp # expect this to be a float

    # handle incorrect input somehow, either here or
    # preferably in the BankAccount#deposit method
    account.deposit(amount)
  when "c"
    puts "Your balance is $%.2f\n" % account.balance
  else
    # didn't understand the command
    puts "Didn't understand your command. Try again." unless cmd == "e"
  end
end
```

Here's the bank account code:

```
# bank_account.rb
class BankAccount
  attr_reader :name, :balance

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @transactions = []
    @balance = 0.0
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    # TODO: check that amount is valid, else error
    @balance -= amount.to_f
    # TODO: check if sufficient funds available
    puts "$%.2f successfully withdrawn.\n" % amount
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    # TODO: check that amount is valid, else error
    @balance += amount.to_f
    puts "$%.2f successfully deposited.\n" % amount
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is perfect, I saved both in two .rb files, atm.rb and bank_account.rb, ran it in CMD and all the functions worked correctly, deposit withdraw check balance and end.  The key shortcuts I requested were also there too.   The next thing I want to do is add an output receipt file.  I'll work on that myself and if I run into trouble, I hope you'll be around again.   Thank you so much again!

Comment: @jmgeronimo you're welcome. Thanks for accepting the answer. I hope you enjoy learning Ruby.